# TaxonomyPicker.ascx failed in SharePoint 2010

Tags: service-applications, service

Is TaxonomyPicker.ascx is SharePoint Default user control ? or 3 rd party user control ?

becasue i received event logs

Load control template file /_controltemplates/TaxonomyPicker.ascx failed: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaxonomyPicker' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

i found the solution on net and blogs, but my concern is what is use of user(TaxonomyPicker.ascx) control ?

This user control is important or not for sharePPoint 2010 Servers.

if important mean where i can found this user control usage ?..

Kindly advice me on this..Advance Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known bug that is easy to fix. Find the control ascx file and correct the five part class identifier, where a period is in the place of a comma.

Comment: Actually the control isnt used In SharePoint at all, so you can just rename the .ascx control to .ascx_something to avoid the error

Answer (score 0):

Load control template file /_controltemplates/TaxonomyPicker.ascx failed 


This issue appears because of the misspelled character ',' (comma) as its # code ',' in the control template. 


The solution is to replace the code with the character by locating the TaxonomyPicker.ascx under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES folder


Now coming to the your question, if you ever happen to go through the SharePoint namespaces you will not find TaxonomyPicker class, thus concluding that the Control Template is not used at all in SharePoint.

PS - I noticed you have an incredible 0% acceptance :-P, mark this as answer if it helped, for the benefit of the community.